# How to group by in list and fill zero

Tags: mysql, sql

I have output list like `{a,b,c,d}`

and table like following

```
type score
a     1
a     2
c     1
```

I would like to group by `type` like following

```
select 
type
,count(type)
from table
group by 1
```

it returned like

```
a 2
c 1
```

But my desired result is like following which is aligned with my desired output list `{a,b,c,d}`

```
a   2
b   0
c   1
d   0
```

How to change my sql to achieve this result ?

If someone has opinion, please let me know

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need some kind of calendar table containing all the types you want to appear in your report.  In lieu of that, you could use an inline union subquery, then left join that to your current table and aggregate by type:

```sql
SELECT c.type, COUNT(t.type) AS cnt
FROM
(
    SELECT 'a' AS type UNION ALL
    SELECT 'b' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'c' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'd'
) c
LEFT JOIN yourTable t
    ON t.type = c.type
GROUP BY
    c.type
ORDER BY
    c.type;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo